# VisualBoyAdvance on Ubuntu (CLI) -- stuck at 85% speed

Tags: ubuntu, emulator

I've installed VisualBoyAdvanced from the Ubuntu repos and loaded my ROM into the game. However, when I play I can't get it to go at regular speed, it's stuck at 85% throttle. I've tried manually setting the throttle to 100%, but that doesn't work.

Also, when I hold the spacebar to "speed up", it get's choppy and is unplayable. Any fixes to this? Does this have anything to do with frame-dropping?

**Edit:** I think it's worth mentioning that I'm not using a GUI for this and I'm on an eeePC. Is it possible that the onboard graphics aren't enough. This seems strange because it's just a GBA game. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I finally figured out how to fix this, however I still don't know WHY is was so slow. The ROM has to be called with VisualBoyAdvance like this:

```
VisualBoyAdvance --flash-128k --throttle=100 --frameskip=3 Path/to/ROM
```

The flash-128k makes some games work better than others, but the key option here is the frameskip. I tried skipping 2 frames and it was quicker but could be better. I decided to use 3 on my eeePC, but see what number works for you.